# Use handlebars to change font-size

Tags: ionic-framework, handlebars.js

I am trying to change the paragraph font-size using handlebars

`<p style="font-size:{{fs}}"> Paragraph</p>`

where `fs='x-small'`

however this is not working. 
What should I change in my code to make it working? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x-small` is not a valid value for the `font-size` CSS property. Instead, add set it as a class on the `<p>` element.

```
<p class="{{fs}}"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks, Sean! I tried the above approach and it worked!